# Youtube API: Starting video doesn't work

Tags: javascript, video, youtube-api

I used the Youtube API to embed a video in my page:
http://ulrichbangert.de/kakteen/rtyt.php
I have an own video (upper) and when this is started the Youtube video (lower) should be started too. Works fine on my desktop PC but on my mobile (Samsung Ace 3) the Youtube video is not started. Why? And how can I fix this? I know that autoplay is disabled on mobile devices but is automatic starting by script also disabled? Or is there another reason why it doesn't work?
Alert when Youtube should be started triggers.
Best regards - Ulrich

Answer (score 1):

Om Chrome for Android (as well as Mobile Safari), any attempt to play a video that isn't initiated by a user action is disallowed (including scripting playback) to avoid unwanted data charges. (The Android native player API doesn't have this restriction, but that's outside the scope of your question!).

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=zh-TW#Mobile_considerations

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. Then I have to accept that it doesn't work as I wanted to. Unfortunately there is another issue: Both videos don't play at the same time; when I start my own video the Youtube video is stopped and vice versa. Is there a solution for this?